# Ugly fonts in Java applications on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, netbeans, pycharm

Help me, please. It's screen of my Netbeans:[image]
PyCharm: [image]
How can I fix it? I use Oracle Java 7.
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

PS: For comparison my Sublime Text:[image]

Comment: it seems your resolution is low, however try to change the font-size, and turn-off anti-aliasing

Comment: It's Java problem, because ST2 has good fonts.

Comment: Its all about `font-rendering` in java and not font itself. DevellMan solution will be the only choice for now, and changing `LookAndFeel` may work for some java softwares (those that support changing `laf`)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

So... Seems my problem is solved.

[Step 1](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html),  Install and configure Infinality for better font rendering in Linux

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality
```

[Step 2.](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/install-openjdk-patched-with-font-fixes.html), Install OpenJDK7 with font fixes in Ubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/openjdk-fontfix
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

NetBeans: [image: screenshot with improved fonts]

Step 3: Applies nice font style linux

```
sudo /etc/fonts/infinality/infctl.sh setstyle linux
```

Comment: May i ask What is your java `LookAndFeel` ? (are you using any or its just how java apps look in `Gnome Shell` ?) because my netbeans installation (7.2) does not look good as yours (although font issue is solved)

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: If you mean theme of my NetBeans - I use standard theme. My os is Elementary  OS and NetBeans goes well with my interface themes.

Comment: Thanks, so you're using GTK look and feel and it just goew better with your GTK theme (I'm using Ubuntu's default Ambiance theme and it just doesn't look good as yours)

Comment: step1 and step2 links's method working fine ! .. thanks for sharing !

Comment: It would be better if you could include essential parts of the steps in the answer! :)

Comment: I got it worked! But today my OpenJDK7 was updated. Now the fonts are screwed up again. Reinstalled infinality and openjdk patch, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: What is this "patched" JDK? What was changed in it? Is it being updated together with the official updates? Seems like a crazy solution to such a problem.

Comment: It's old solution, and maybe not actual for now

Comment: Why do you need `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: I didn't have a clue there were these great patches around. Thanks a lot! Everything looks much better now!

Answer (score 45):

Try adding

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp'
```

to your ~/.bashrc

A more detailed discussion can be found [here](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_Fonts#Basic_settings).

Comment: with
    '-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on' on my webstorm looks good

Comment: What sorcery is this? This magically made the fonts in umongo beautiful. Why doesn't Java do this by default!? Seriously, check out the [before](http://gyazo.com/e62e8e7c7168e6f9a74dcef73ae75a7e) and [after](http://i.gyazo.com/990c5d0cefffe18faaa235534139693d.png), it's ridiculous

Comment: Hubro: A bit better, but still really bad.

Comment: Adding this to my bashrc didn't work, so I added `System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "on");` to the source of the program

Comment: Excellent, only I would put it in `/etc/environment` as a system-wide fix.

Comment: There is no need to set the env variable (setting env vars in different shells might be tricky, for example, tcsh `export` won't work). You can pass it as command line argument to `java` command: `java -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on ...`.

Comment: Used this as an argument to `java` call and worked like a charm. As a plus it doesn't need additional repos etc. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 21):

Old topic but for future visits, here is a solution that works:

```bash
# Install both infinality and fontfix'ed JDK.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/openjdk-fontfix
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality openjdk-7-jdk
# Apply a font style that looks good.
sudo /etc/fonts/infinality/infctl.sh setstyle linux
# And reboot the system.
sudo reboot
```

source : Demian Ferreiro in [solution](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57233#comment=27-472038)

Comment: Finally! This actaully worked for me. My anorexic fonts are gone.

Comment: If you need to use oracle's java for one reason or another, installing `fontconfig-infinality` and then running `sudo /etc/fonts/infinality/infctl.sh setstyle` and selecting `linux` or `osx` also works as per Ian Wong's answer (which is hidden a bit further down at the moment).

Answer (score 11):

After hours of searching and experimenting, I finally found a working solution!!! No need to mess up with fontforge, no need to patch your jdk, which is not allowed on a corporate workstation.

1. *REQUIRED* [Remove openjdk and install oracle jdk.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)
2. Download deb from http://ppa.launchpad.net/no1wantdthisname/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig-infinality/
3. Install it: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
4. Enable osx font smoothing: `sudo /etc/fonts/infinality/infctl.sh setstyle`
5. Reboot your system `sudo reboot lightgdm`

If you are an Android Studio (Intellij) user, try add the following lines to your studio(64).vmoptions:

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
-Dswing.aatext=true
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
```

Comment: Fantastic! This makes applications like freeplane and cytoscape so much easier to use, I can actually read the menu items now! The styles `linux` and `osx` both worked for me, `infinality` did not look very good.

Answer (score 3):

As of version release 2016.1, JetBrains is including / bundling a JRE that has the font rendering corrected.

:)

Scott

Comment: This breaked my fonts this morning after the update :(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing the choice of font in the program's settings.  You can also [install the windows fonts](http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/09/installing-microsoft-fonts/) on Ubuntu if you prefer these.

In both cases you should be able to chose File -> Settings and search for font and change it to whatever you like.

I use a proportional font in IntelliJ CE and it looks fine to me in Ubuntu.

Comment: Changing fonts does not help.

Comment: Have you turned on anti-aliasing (which I believe is off by default)  It is not clear to me why you find it ugly so I am just guessing.

Comment: yes @PeterLawrey is right, anti-aliasing is not just belong to software, you may check the VGA Driver config too