# How to load and use Liberation fonts under Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, fonts

I know the Liberation Sans font is installed - I used getLocalGraphicsEnvironment() and getAllFonts() to verify.  But I have not been able to use the Liberation Sans font on Ubuntu; Java always defaults to (what appears to be) Lucida.

How do I load and use Liberation Sans?

(btw I understand to use Arial in production requires a license.)

Answer (score 0):

This [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_fonts#Basic_settings) suggests to use something like:

> Some Java applications may specify use of a particular TrueType font; these applications must be made aware of the directory path to the desired font. TrueType fonts are installed in the directory /usr/share/fonts/TTF. Add the following line to /etc/environment to enable these fonts.
>
> JAVA_FONTS=/usr/share/fonts/TTF

That is for Arch Linux, but hey, Linux should be Linux, somehow.

So, lets hope it works for you. When it does not, you might have some luck on this existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510099/ugly-fonts-in-java-applications-on-ubuntu), albeit it dates 6 years back.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I spent some time at the site you mention above, and adding JAVA_FONTS as an environment variable might be why I see fonts are available.